Aquring a stock certificate for a Medallion stamp
My father recently passed. He left my sister's and I his UPS stock through Computershare. We are trying to divide it between the 3 of us. Computershare is requiring is to get a medallion stamp to transfer the stock. For the medallion stamp we need a stock certificate which we can't seem to find in our dad's paperwork. How do we go about receiving a new stock certificate.?

If he held the stock through computershare then there's no certificate. Medallion stamp is akin to a notary stamp, but in the financial industry. What is it that they're asking to "notarize"?

We are trying to get the stock out of his name and into our computershare accounts that he created for us years ago that we already have stock in. So I guess because of the amount of stock there is its a liability thing.

What I mean is that medallion stamp authenticates a signature. What did they ask you to sign?

A medallion stamp is a certification by a bank that they know you and have witnessed your signature. It is a stronger version of notarizing the signature, since banks require a higher level of proof of identity due to such things as "know your customer" laws.
You do not need the stock certificate in order to get a medallion stamp on paperwork. You need to be an established customer of the bank that is providing this service, and be able to prove that you are that person, and you need to bring the document that a medallion certification is required on, unsigned until the bank officer tells you to do so.
If the transfer itself requires specifying them stock certificate number, that is a separate matter from the medallion certification. The medallion does not attest to the accuracy or completeness of the document, only to the fact that it was signed by the right person.
